# Whats the name of the place where facebook, skype, and other iOS apps got code from?

Tags: ios, facebook, ipad, xcode4.2, skype

I was on here searching for other stuff and stumbled upon a website that had a demo on the site of an iphone and showed a bunch of stock views and tableviews. I remember it saying that a bunch of big apps used their source. Like facebook and skype. I tried searching everywhere for it again. Does anyone know what I'm talking about?

Comment: check your browsers history and post the link

Answer (score 2):

Was it [Three20](http://three20.info) perhaps?

Comment: Bingo! Thanks that's exactly it!

Answer (score 0):

GitHub?
www.github.com

Repository for social, open source code sharing.

Comment: it wasn't github it was a business can't remember if it was open source or not

Answer (score 0):

Search Three20 on Google! ;) There are many UI codes!